# Trouble setting default value for a member variable in JSF

Tags: jsf-2, managed-bean

```
package no.northcreek.mabjo;
import javax.annotation.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;

@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class indexBean {

    @ManagedProperty(value="defaultValue")
    private String firstName;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }  
}
```

So above is a code I expect to create the firstName member variable with a default value of "defaultValue". However the value is null. Why?

Comment: As a matter of fact this code worked as knife-in-butter when applied on a different environment (OS). So I guess you could argue that the @ManagedProperty was never intended to provide default scalar values, but it *can* be used for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that you misunderstood the usage of *@ManagedProperty*

> @ManagedProperty annotation is used to dependency injection (DI) a managed bean into the property of another managed bean.

and note that *value* should point to an ELxpression , like this : `value="#{someBean}"`

In your case you should just do the following

```
private String firstName = "defaultValue";
```

OR

init the value of `firstName` in your `@PostConstruct`

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
  firstName = "defaultValue";
}
```

take a look at this example...

[Injecting Managed beans in JSF 2.0](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/injecting-managed-beans-in-jsf-2-0/)